# Coredata background saving, sync strategies and conflict resolution

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

This is more of an architectural question so I'm not sure if it is a good fit for this site, but I thought I'd give it a try anyway.

Upon login, one of our apps fetches `Item` updates from the server based on the latest timestamp saved locally. So any records newer than the newest local timestamp get downloaded and imported into the database.

This all happens in a background thread using a local managed object context.

The app also downloads `ItemCollection` instances from the server (created via CMS), which are essentially collections of `Item` instances.

While new `Item` instances are being downloaded/created in the background, another process is fetching `ItemCollection` items from the same server.

Each `ItemCollection` has a `name` attribute and an array of `ItemIDs` imported as a Coredata relationship.

Sometimes the `ItemCollection` import will reference an `ItemUniqueID` that has not yet been created by the background process. In this case we create a placeholder `Item` that only contains its `ItemUniqueID` and is flagged as placehoder/pending processing.

So between these two imports, there is a high probability of duplicate items being created.

The `ItemCollection` import process may create an `Item` with ID=1, while the same item could be created on the background thread that is downloading and processing `Items` from the server, and we will end up with two `Item` instances referencing the same `ID==1`.

Because the two processing are running concurrently, in separate threads and using separate managed object contexts, the only time these duplicate objects will be aware of each other is when we call `save` on the `managedObjectContext` in the main thread.

**So the TL;DR version of my question is how can I ensure two separate managed object contexts do not create/update/delete NSManagedObject duplicates and when that happens, what is the correct way to deal with it using some sort of conflict resolution?**

Thanks,
Rog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your own unique id.  That's good.  However, each context could have its own view of the data, unknown to the other because the store has not been updated.  This could cause false readings/interpretations.

You can try to manage this by watching `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` which will allow each context to know about what the other is doing, and thus know when objects with the same unique ID have appeared.  However, this may be more effort than it's worth.

Why do you have to do the downloads at the same time?

Why not perform one download, and when that one is done, perform the other download?  It makes the architecture much simpler, and the simpler the better.  Your implementation also benefits from having less code, and less chance for bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Having the downloads happen synchronously would be ideal however sometimes the processing of `Items` can take > 5minutes depending on how many have been updated/created, while typically the processing of `ItemCollections` is almost instant. Doing the processing synchronously would affect user experience as their ItemCollections would take considerably longer to download/appear on the app.

Comment: That does give me an idea though as I could process collections first, create the appropriate placeholders for missing items and once that's done kick off the processing of items. I'll look into it and report back, thanks again.

Comment: @Rog Yes, I would suggest processing the collection objects first.  If you already have code to deal with an "almost created" item, then it's a simple matter or coordinating them.  Also, don't forget to process all those items in batches if you can.  It prevents memory issues, and makes the UI look more responsive because updates are constantly coming in.

Comment: @Rog Better yet, I have found that for this type of data model it can work better to give each collection a unique id, and then let the items keep track of the collection.  That way, you add the collection, and there are no partially hydrated objects in it.  When you upload the individual items, you know exactly which collection(s) they belong to.  In fact, to go further, I've also found it easier in Core Data to keep that same philosophy where the objects know their containment relationship rather than the collection keeping track of all the individual objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like your solution very much :(. The two calls/threads you are doing to the server are very dependent on each other and from my point of view things should be kept easy. What is the point of using two threads, were the data are "tightly coupled"?

When you retrive the ItemsCollection, can you at the same time retrive your Item data? (I mean in the same server call). That would be the perfect solution (JSON/XML with ItemCollection and Items), and you will avoid a lot of headaches.

How can you be sure that the items in each ItemCollection are (or will be) in the CoreData store? These are the kind of questions you will have to handle.

In case you can't get all the info a the same time, I would store the ItemCollection data temporaly in an struct until all the items from the first call are saved.

Regards,
Angel